# Need help pointing out mistake $\oint (z^2 − z + 2) dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Need help solving:

$\oint (z^2 − z + 2) dz$

[image]

I believe that the $\int_c=\int_{c_1}+\int_{c_2}$

1) With the first parametric equation is to equal to $t+i$

$$\int({z^2 − z + 2})dt=\int_0^1{(t+i)^2 − (t+i) + 2}dt$$
$$\int_0^1t^2+2ti-1-t-i+2dt$$
$$\int_0^1(t^2-t+1)dt+i\int_0^1(2t-1)dt$$
$$\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}+t]_0^1+{it^2}-it]^1_0$$
$$\frac{5}{6}+0=\frac{5}{6}=c_1$$

2) With the second parametric equation to $1+it$

$$\int({z^2 − z + 2})dt=\int_1^0{(1+it)^2 − (1+it) + 2}dt$$
$$\int_1^0(-t^2-2ti+1-it+2)dt$$
$$-\int_0^1(-t^2-2ti+1-it+2)dt$$
$$\int_0^1(t^2+2ti-1-t+it-2)dt$$
$$\int_0^1(t^2-t-3)dt+i\int_0^1(2t+1)dt$$
$$\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^2}{2}-3t]_0^1+{it^2}+it]^1_0$$
$$\frac{-19}{6}+2i=\frac{-19}{6}+2i=c_2$$

3) To finally get

$$\int_{c_1}+\int_{c_2}=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{-19}{6}+2i=\frac{-7}{3}+2i$$

However when ever i solve it I keep getting it reduced down to $\frac{-7}{3}+2i$ which is not the correct answer. The answer for the books solution says 0 but both answers are wrong. I'm not sure if I have the parameter wrong or what?

Comment: 1) The notation $\oint$ usually refers to an integral around a closed loop, which seems not to match with your path of integration. Are you sure you are not supposed to take the integral around the whole square? 2) I think you oriented the second path to go from $1$ to $1+i$, so you probably picked up a negative sign there that you have to take into account, i.e. "$\int_c = \int_{c_1} - \int_{c_2}$"

Comment: Are you sure that the intended contour is not a closed loop?  The fact that the intended answer is 0 makes me think it should be (see the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).)

Comment: It is very strange to think that the intent would be to integrate around a closed loop when the diagram is very clearly drawn in such a manner.  The diagram would need to be drawn with two additional arrows along the coordinate axes in the appropriate direction.  To not do this is a serious oversight on the part of the creator of the problem.

Comment: @heropup:  The diagram should definitely be drawn differently if this was the intent, but it's possible that either (a) the diagram was drawn by the OP, who was confused about the intent;  or (b) the diagram was drawn by some inattentive schlub in a graphic-arts department of a publishing house, who missed the extra arrows intended by the author.  (The latter should have been caught by an editor or the author, but errata in published textbooks still do happen.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of whether the contour is supposed to be an open path or a closed one, you do have an error in your second integral.  Specifically, if you are parameterizing the curve as $z = 1 + it$ with $t$ running from 1 to 0, then you do not have $dz = dt$ but rather
$$
dz = d(1 + it) = i \, dt.
$$
So 
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_2} (z^2 - z + 2) \, dz &= \int_1^0 [ (-t^2 + 2it + 1) - (1 + it) + 2 ] (i \, dt) \\
&= i \int_1^0 (it) dt + i \int_1^0 (-t^2+ 2) dt  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{5}{3} i.
\end{align*}
(You also made a few algebra errors in when you were combining your terms.)

Comment: Thank you!! The concepts were clicking but the Algebra was tedious when you move quickly!!